# .htaccess redirect everything on root folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my sites, when type `www.abc.com/folder`, it's redirect to `index.php`. And I want the script don't touch on others folder and files. So is there anyway to prevent this?

This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect everything from root only to home page you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ / [L,R]

RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```